# Tool for finding ways to get an object instance inside the debugger?

Tags: c#, reflection

Right now I'm looking at a bug in some C# code where I need to get a given object instance at some location. I'm sitting on a breakpoint at that location in the debugger and can jump back up the stack and view the object instance that I need to get. I suspect that there is a way to get that instance from what I have (`foo.bar.baz.bla.bla.bla` or something like that) but I'm not knowledgeable enough about the code to know how to find it.

*Hypothetical Example:*

> I'm sitting in the debugger at line 2485 in some one eases code and realize that the program needs to, right here, set the `FooBat` property on the enclosing `WizBang` object (the one that the function 27 steps up the call stack was called on) but I don't have any direct references to the enclosing `WizBang` object. However I suspect that one of the other object I do have access to has access to something that has access to something that does have access to the enclosing `WizBang` object. But that gives me about 10K things to look through and, oh by the way, I can also access 42 different `WizBang` objects that are not the one I want so I also need to check that it really is the same object as the one 27 steps up the stack. If I can just find how to get access to it I can add `SomeExp.FooBat = true;` right here on line 2485 and close this bug!

*My question is: has anyone made a tool that uses reflection and bruit force to search chains of properties and members to find one that will give a desired object instance?*

Yes I know this is an `O(b`<sup>`d`</sup>`)` problem and often won't work but it's computer time, not programmer time and when it does work, it would be fantastic!

p.s. I give it less than even odd of what I want existing (now `<g/>`).

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question but I can't think of a better example than was already in the question.

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by 'find'.  Do you want to view the instance members in the debugger, do you want to get their source location, do you want to create an instance of it...etc

Comment: I want to find an expression that, if evaluated from some context would give some particular object instance. The situation is that I have to edit my code to modify a specific object instance from a specific context and I want the computer to tell me ways I can do it.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should try the "Immediate window" where you can enter c# live. It can evaluate only expressions and assignments (no declarations etc).

You can find the immediate window from Debug->Windows->Immediate (Ctrl-Alt-I by default)

Did you try that already?

Comment: That allows me to test IF an expression gets me what I want, but it sill has me manually searching though the options.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the watch-window of the visual-studio debugger. You could insert your instance once and watch it every step.

Comment: See my comment on the question: I need an expression that I can edit into my code. This question stems from a debugging session where I realized that to fix a bug, I needed to use an object that, using the debugger, I could see in another stack frame but I couldn't figure out how to get access to from the place where I needed it.

Comment: You can modify objects on VS' Watch Window.
Also, you seem to have a doubt on Reflection. You can grab pretty much everything with Reflection.

Comment: I rather suspect that poping a message box asking the end user to use the debugger to edit stuff isn't going to fly. I need an expression that can be used in the final product, not just a way to get it to run right now.

Answer (score 0):

Although reading all your comments and posts I'm not sure whether I correctly understood what you want. Did you try conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio? They may help as well. You can use them to check whether your object fulfills some conditions and just stop in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something that you would have to write yourself. That said, I don't imagine it to be very difficult - after all, you just need to write a method that uses reflection to traverse whatever object structure you're working with, checking for a specific condition. Then, you simply set a breakpoint (or hit Pause) and then run your method on whatever object structure you need. You can probably set the method to `[Conditional(DEBUG)]` so it doesn't appear in the release version of your program.

Comment: That would be a highly limited, ad-hoc solution to what I want (OTOH you seem to be the first person that gets my question <g>). I'd love to see a tool that does this, but I'm not interested enough to write one my self.